# How does Boost::log print with the same indentation?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

I am trying to create a log format:

```
expr::stream
            << "[" << expr::format_date_time< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
            << "] [" << logging::trivial::severity
            << "]  " << expr::message;
```

Which outputs:

```
[2020-05-06 12:25:00.978764] [info]  Testing
[2020-05-06 12:25:00.978880] [trace]  Testingtrace
```

This, however, is the default console log:

```
[2020-05-06 12:17:23.190613] [0x00007eff5e9767c0] [info]    Testing
[2020-05-06 12:17:23.190677] [0x00007eff5e9767c0] [trace]   Testingtrace
```

As you can see despite the fact that "info" stamp is shorter than trace, both messages start at the same indentation.

I wanted to do this by comparing and setting the number of spaces according to the severity level, starting by doing a test with "info" but this:

```
logging::trivial::severity == logging::trivial::info
```

Is not a valid boolean expression.

Does anyone know how the default format is defined and how could I go about achieving this.

Comment: presumably just using `setw` with the largest possible severity string length would work?

Comment: Wow thanks, I'm a bit ashamed to say I had never heard of this option!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is wondering, although setw works too, as indicated by [Alan Birtles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61635208/how-does-boostlog-print-with-the-same-indentation#comment109025100_61635208), the easier solution is to simply use \t:

```
expr::stream
            << "[" << expr::format_date_time< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
            << "] " << "[" << logging::trivial::severity
            << "]\t" << expr::message;
```

Output:

```
[2020-05-06 12:56:41.741449] [info]     Testing
[2020-05-06 12:56:41.741783] [trace]    Testingtrace
[2020-05-06 12:56:41.741826] [warning]  Testingtrace
```

I don't know how I didn't think about this before...smh